# Criar mock da camada service utilizando nodejs e Jest

Tags: node.js, testes, jest

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Node.js que consiste em várias camadas, incluindo controller, model, route e service. Atualmente, estou enfrentando um desafio ao escrever testes para as camadas de controller e service usando o Jest. Para ilustrar o problema, gostaria de compartilhar um exemplo de um método da camada de controller:

```js
controller.listarChamadosEmAtendimento = (req, resp) => {
    return chamadoService
      .listarChamadosEmAtendimento(sanitizeXSS(req).string('tipoFornecedor'))
      .then(listaChamados => {
        resp.header("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains").status(200).send(listaChamados);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        resp.header("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains").status(500).send(error);
      });
  };
```

Observe que esse método faz uma chamada para chamadoService.listarChamadosEmAtendimento(), que, por sua vez, realiza uma consulta em um banco de dados e retorna os dados com base nos parâmetros.

Comecei a criar um teste com o código abaixo:

```js
  it('método listarChamadosEmAtendimento', async () => {

    const mockReq = {
      params: {
        tipoFornecedor: 2
      },
      body: {
        tipoFornecedor: 2
      },
      query: {
        tipoFornecedor: 2
      }
    }; 
    
    const mockResp = {
      header: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), 
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), 
      send: jest.fn(), 
    };
  
    await controller.listarChamadosEmAtendimento(mockReq, mockResp);

    expect(mockResp.header).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
    expect(mockResp.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);

  });
```

O desafio que estou enfrentando é criar um mock para chamadoService.listarChamadosEmAtendimento(), o que é essencial para que o teste funcione. No entanto, não posso configurar um banco de dados para executar os testes, pois isso gera erros ao usar uma ferramenta de CI/CD. Acredito que seja necessário criar um mock para chamadoService.listarChamadosEmAtendimento() e definir um valor de retorno de mock quando o método controller.listarChamadosEmAtendimento(mockReq, mockResp) for chamado. No entanto, se houver outra abordagem que possa resolver esse problema, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Cara, existe uma lib pra isso, é a [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon), esta [publicação](https://danizavtz.com.br/como-aumentar-a-cobertura-dos-testes-de-seu-codigo-com-sinon/) pode ajudar a entender e aplicar no teu caso.

Comment: Tu pode compartilhar a tua solução? Vou criar uma resposta aí tu edita, vai servir pra a comunidade. Pode ser?

Comment: eu não sei como terminar a resposta, mas deixei como um wiki da comunidade.  Aí tu pode complementar pra deixar ele funcional 100%? Não tenho o jest, configurado em nenhum projeto, então não tenho como testar, mas como tu já implementou, então tem tudo que é necessário para deixar o entendimento 100%. Inclulsive pode mudar tudo, ou então criar a tua resposta...

Comment: @Danizavtz irei editar e compartilhar a solução.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Danizavtz pela ajuda na solução do problema.

Comment: tmj, vlw pela contribuição :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Passo-a-passo da solução utilizando a lib sinon:

Instalar o Sinon como uma dependência de desenvolvimento.

```
 npm install sinon --save-dev
```

- importar o serviço `chamadoService` no spec de teste
- mockar o req e resp do método `listarChamadosEmAtendimento`

Em seu arquivo de teste, importar a lib sinon. Importar o módulo `chamadoService`. Criar um stub para o método `listarChamadosEmAtendimento`.

Uma implementação concreta seria a seguinte:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chamadoService = require('../caminho/relativo/para/service');

//resto das configurações
//aqui a implementação concreta
it.only('método listarChamadosEmAtendimento', async () => {

    const mockReq = {
      params: {
        tipoFornecedor: 2
      },
      body: {
        tipoFornecedor: 2
      },
      query: {
        tipoFornecedor: 2
      }
    };
   
    // nesse trecho foi corrigido o problema, foi substituida a função real pela abaixo  
    sinon.stub(chamadoService, 'listarChamadosEmAtendimento').resolves([1, 2, 3]);

    const mockResp = {
      header: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), 
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), 
      send: jest.fn(), 
    };

    await controller.listarChamadosEmAtendimento(mockReq, mockResp);

    expect(mockResp.header).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
    expect(mockResp.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
    
    const mockResp500 = {
      header: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), 
      status: jest.fn(() => 500).mockReturnThis(), 
      send: jest.fn(() => mockResp500), 
    };

    mockResp500.status.mockImplementation((statusCode) => {
      expect(statusCode).toBe(500); 
      return mockResp500; 
    });
    
    await controller.listarChamadosEmAtendimento(mockReq, mockResp500);

    expect(mockResp500.header).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
    expect(mockResp500.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);

  });
```

Foi utilizando o "resolves" como retorno dos valores, pois o then() do método "controller.listarChamadosEmAtendimento" espera uma promessa resolvida. Com isso o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Danizavtz pela ajuda na solução do problema.